# How can I test file downloads with Behat 3 when using FileSaver.js?

Tags: javascript, php, selenium-webdriver, behat

I'm developing some Behat 3 (with Selenium 2) tests for a site that uses FileSaver.js to convert some DOM elements into an XML file for download. (I can't change that bit, so don't ask.)

When I click a button, JavaScript fires that passes the data blob into FileSaver.js, which converts that to an actual file and activates your browser's usual file download dialog. From there, the user clicks ok and says where to save the file.

I would like to test this process, but I can't figure out how to actually *click that OK button or select where to save the file*.

I'm fairly new to Behat, but the closest I could find to this is another SO question that deals with a file download ([How to test file download in Behat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24930276/how-to-test-file-download-in-behat)), but because this blob file is created on the fly, I can't just use Guzzle to pull the file from the server.

Any suggestions?

Comment: you can setup the browser both to not ask if and to not ask where.

Comment: @dandavis Care to elaborate?

Comment: @KyleOliveira did you ever find a solution for this?

Comment: @ScottAnderson No, we gave up on testing that particular aspect in that way. If anybody finds a way to do that, I think it'd be a really neat thing to know though!