# How to test file download using Behat version 3

Tags: php, yaml, behat

I implement the function in FeatureContext, but I do not know how to config in behat.yml

## Here is my code

FeatureContext.php

```
/**
 * @Then /^the file ".+" should be downloaded$/
 * @param $filename
 *
 * @throws \Exception
 */
public function assertFileDownloaded($filename) {
    if (!file_exists('/download/dir/' . $filename)) {
        throw new Exception("Can not download");
    }
}
```

**Download.feature**

```
Scenario: Download unlock documents with Success Stories
  When I am on "managed-security-services/downloads/"
  Then I should be on "/managed-security-services/downloads/"
  And I should see "Bühler"
  Then I click on the text "Bühler"
  And I wait for "1" seconds
  And the file ".+" should be downloaded
```

I do not know how to pass argument to behat.yml
Here is code

```
suites:
    default:
      paths: &featurePaths
        - '%paths.base%/features'
      contexts: &contexts
        - FeatureContext
```

**When I run my test it shows message error like this:**

> [Behat\Testwork\Argument\Exception\UnknownParameterValueException]                                               Can not find a matching value for an argument `$filename` of the method `FeatureContext::assertFileDownloaded()`.

As reference in here [How to test file download in Behat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24930276/how-to-test-file-download-in-behat?answertab=active#tab-top)

Comment: There may be something usefull for you in http://www.inanzzz.com/index.php/posts/behat

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
/**
 * @Then /^the file :filename should be downloaded$/
 *
 * @throws \Exception
 */
public function assertFileDownloaded($filename) {
    if (!file_exists('/download/dir/' . $filename)) {
        throw new Exception("Can not download");
    }
}
```